# Is there a way to improve val_acc?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, talos

**Context:**

I am trying to train a image classifier on [kaggle cell dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/blood-cells) of hopefully 0.95 val_acc. I have tried many model architectures and number of epochs, among several other hyperparameters arriving at a promising set that yields a 0.9 val_acc.

**Things I tried:**

- shuffled image label pair together, so correct label stays with image
- normalize images so each pixel is between 0 and 1
- added `BatchNormalization()`, `Dropout()` to reduce overfitting (now model is underfitting)
- [permutations of hyperparameters tried](https://github.com/NicholasGoh/CNN/blob/master/kaggle_cells/cell_results/112119203842.csv)

**Problem:**

The set of hyperparameters that gave the best val_acc still plateus at 0.9. I have tried many permutations, is there anything I am missing/doing wrong?

**Model:**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 120, 160, 8)       224       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 120, 160, 8)       32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 120, 160, 8)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 120, 160, 8)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 60, 80, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 60, 80, 8)         32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 60, 80, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 60, 80, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 60, 80, 8)         32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 60, 80, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 80, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 40, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 30, 40, 8)         32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 30, 40, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 40, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 30, 40, 8)         32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 30, 40, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 30, 40, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 20, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 15, 20, 8)         32        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 15, 20, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 20, 16)        3216      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 15, 20, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 15, 20, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 15, 20, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 10, 16)         6416      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 8, 10, 16)         64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 8, 10, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 10, 16)         6416      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (Batch (None, 8, 10, 16)         64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 8, 10, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 8, 10, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 5, 16)          6416      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (Batch (None, 4, 5, 16)          64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 4, 5, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 320)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 240)               77040     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (Batc (None, 240)               960       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 240)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 162)               39042     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (Batc (None, 162)               648       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 162)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 84)                13692     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (Batc (None, 84)                336       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 84)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 340       
=================================================================
Total params: 158,114
Trainable params: 156,918
Non-trainable params: 1,196
```

[visualization of activations and val_acc, val_loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTlu.jpg)

**Note:**

The optimization was done using `talos` which can be found [here](http://github.com/autonomio/talos). I edited and added some modules [here](https://github.com/NicholasGoh/CNN/tree/master/talos_model).

---

**Edit 1:**

The optimizer I used is Nadam with learning rate 0.0002. [Full notebook](https://github.com/NicholasGoh/CNN/blob/master/kaggle_cells/cells.ipynb).

**TLDR:**

Trained on [kaggle cell dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/blood-cells) using best hyperparameters from a test run of trying around 200 different hyperparameters. Plateaus at 0.9. Why not higher?

[full notebook](https://github.com/NicholasGoh/CNN/blob/master/kaggle_cells/cells.ipynb)

Comment: What optimizer are you using?

Comment: Please add your full architecture, also, keep in mind you should try always to overfit first and then try regularization methods to achieve a similar val_acc. Once you share more information regarding your network we can help you a bit more!

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Thanks for the prompt replies. I have made an edit accordingly. The optimizer I used is Nadam and the learning rate is 0.0002. Thanks in advance for any insights you guys provide!

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can find, I was using too low a learning rate. Increasing it seems to help.